# Errors while applying force on a model

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I apply a force:
rosservice call /gazebo/apply_body_wrench '{body_name: "quadrotor::link", reference_frame: "quadrotor::link", wrench: { force: { x: 0, y: 0, z: -20.0 } }, start_time: 0, duration: -1 }'
And get the error: [ERROR] [1371151542.440105542, 5372.627000000]: wrench defined as [link]:[0.000000 0.000000 -20.000000, 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000] --> applied as [link]:[0.000000 0.000000 -20.000000, 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000]

Please help.
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65077/errors-while-applying-force-on-a-model/) by [Mrit91](https://answers.ros.org/users/5003/mrit91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-06-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the source code gazebo_ros_api_plugin.cpp under line 01553, it seems to always print out that error message as long as you set a reference frame other than empty, map, or world.

---

Originally posted by [Gooly](https://answers.ros.org/users/18646/gooly/) with karma: 26 on 2014-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1